# How to collect Sleep Cycle/Sleep Stages in standalone WearOS application?

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, healthconnect

My task: collecting information about sleep stages (AWAKE, SLEEPING, DEEP and etc.) in a standalone WearOS application.

We currently use **Health Services** to collect information about steps, distance, and calories.
I didn't find any information about collecting sleep information in the official documentation for Health Services.

1. Can **Health Services** be used to collect sleep information?

I found information about sleep stages on Health Connect. [Here](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-connect/develop/sessions) is how you can read and write this information.

2. Can I use **Health Connect** in my WearOS app?
3. Is it necessary to analyze some parameters to determine the stage of sleep? How to do this automatically?

And my common question:
How to collect Sleep Cycle/Sleep Stages in standalone WearOS application?

Answer (score 1):

1. Health Services can be used to [detect UserActivityState](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-services/monitor-background#useractivityinfo), which can tell you if a user is asleep. It doesn't provide details on sleep stages.
2. Health Connect cannot be used in a standalone Wear OS app and is specific to a mobile device. To have Health Connect interaction with a Wear OS app, it would need to be facilitated through an accompanying mobile app.
3. Additional parameters would be needed to assess sleep stages